# Error value returned even though all tests pass

Tags: googletest

I have a C++ googletests (gmock 1.6.0) project which passes all tests but will occasionally return a error value of -1073740940 instead of the expected 0.

I've got the googletest project executing itself as a post-build step, and here's the end of its output:

```
148>  [----------] Global test environment tear-down
148>  [==========] 343 tests from 32 test cases ran. (190 ms total)
148>  [  PASSED  ] 343 tests.
148>  
148>    YOU HAVE 2 DISABLED TESTS
148>  
148>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(134,5): error MSB3073: The command "IF [%NO_RUN_TESTS%] EQU [] ("Win32\Release\Tests.exe")
148>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(134,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code -1073740940.
```

Here's is the main():

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

What could cause this to return non-zero when all of the tests pass?  Is there a way to keep it from happening?

Comment: Looks very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915799/how-to-keep-build-failing-when-post-build-step-fails but also unanswered...

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior 4 years later with GMock 1.10.